# Error installing Eclipse PDT in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I installed my Eclipse via the Ubuntu Software Center. Afterwhich, I follow the instruction in this wiki (http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.5_.2F_Galileo_.2F_PDT_2.2) and I met with the following errors:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) Runtime Feature 2.2.0.v200912030932-7L7J-F8NcJKhTcJmKhmc (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 2.2.0.v200912030932-7L7J-F8NcJKhTcJmKhmc)
  Missing requirement: PHP Development Tools (PDT) Runtime Feature 2.2.0.v200912030932-7L7J-F8NcJKhTcJmKhmc (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 2.2.0.v200912030932-7L7J-F8NcJKhTcJmKhmc) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found

I tried googling but I can't find any instruction on how to install 'org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: @ILMV: Installing Eclipse on ServerFault? IMO it's a developer's question.

Comment: I agree, this is a question that developers can help with, certainly not sysadmins and probably not superusers.  I think it should stay here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses. However, none really works with the Ubuntu version of Eclipse. What I did in the end is to download the zip from Eclipse and follow the eclipse section of this installation manual.

http://flurdy.com/docs/eclipse/install.html

Thanks again for all the responses :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the Webtools (WST) installed. Try installing it from the update site at: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates. Under Web Tools Platform you will find Eclipse XSL Developer Tools which is what you are looking for. Also make sure you install DLTK 2.0 from the update site mentioned on the page (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/2.0/).

Note that you are attempting to install a development version of PDT (2.2), which may be a bit tricky. For general purpose you should use the release version of PDT (2.1). To install the latest release package, it is based to go to http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo and install the EPP PHP Feature (EPP stands for Eclipse Packaging Project). This installs everything you need in one need package.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about installing from repository. Install [Eclipse PDT all in one package](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/). This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but I suspect it could be that the PHP infrastructure is missing. Try something like:

```
apt-get install php
```

or use the Synaptic package manager to install PHP

and see if that helps!

Comment: i tried apt-get install php5 and rerun the installation of pdt according to the wiki, still having the exact same problem.

Comment: Then I'm sorry - for the moment I have no better advice! :(

Answer (score 0):

WST is the web tools stuff.  You can get this by installing the Java EE version of Eclipse from which you can download from eclipse.org.  Alternatively you can add the [Galileo update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/Galileo/) and install the webtools stuff from there.  In fact, after adding that update site and retrying your PDT installation it might (should) just work.

Comment: I thinking of trying out the update site, but I'm getting a "no software site" error. Is the link valid to be added in the "Install New Software" I tried searching for other update sites but i'm not sure where to start and begin. Exact step is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, it's sort of misleading, there is nothing for the browser to see there.  Do Help -> Install New Software, then click the Add button.  Put the link there.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems using plugins with Ubuntu's stock version of Eclipse in Jaunty. Jaunty's Eclipse was a couple of versions behind. Ended up installing Eclipse directly from eclipse.org.

Comment: I never get Eclipse from distos they are always old.

Answer (score 0):

try downloading the eclipse classic (usually around 161 megs) and make sure you've added the dltk update site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Karmic Koala, open Terminal and:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yogarine/eclipse/ubuntu`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install eclipse-pdt`

Note: *For a long time I have been using standalone Eclipse PDT apart from the repository one. With this [wonderful update by **yogarine**](http://blog.yogarine.com/2009/10/eclipse-plugin-packages-for-ubuntu.html) I switched to the repository package at once. It works way faster for me!*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out my "Eclipse update site" was not populated as noted here by Francis... however, his link had a capital G where it should have been a lower case "g"

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

use that in your software sites if having this issue.  of course, this presents another issue to me at least, which is:

An error occurred while installing the items
  session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.ant.ui 3.4.1.v20090901_r351, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
  The artifact file for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.4.1.v20090901_r351 was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. In order to do a successful install from the **Help -> Install New Software** menu I had to add *two* extra sources, above and beyond the DLTK and PDT sources mentioned in the installation instructions (http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation).

These were:

download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo (*as mentioned above*)
download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5

HTH

Andy